# Is there a Stack Exchange site where website recommendations are on-topic?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I've tried asking for recommendations on DNS hosting/registrars only to have had the questions punted multiple times and result in responses telling me that it's on-topic elsewhere, that I've not phrased it correctly, that it is actually off-topic, etc. Is there any section of the Stack Exchange network where I can list a set of requirements for a DNS host/registrar and ask if any exist that fit those criteria and have it be on-topic?

Comment: Maybe http://slant.co would be of help.

Comment: What about [webmasters.SE]?

Comment: Not Webmasters, but maybe their chat.

Answer (score 5):

No. The only recommendation site is [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) but even there this would be off topic.